# pyodbc install on heroku server error command "gcc" failed with exit status 1 - Django project

Tags: django, heroku, pip, pyodbc

I'm running an heroku app, and using pyODBC.

I get this error when i try to install pyodbc on my heroku server.

The same thing happends when I try putting pyodbc in the requirements.txt file.

I simply don't understand what to do from this error, and I can't seem to find how to use commands like sudo apt-get on the heroku server through the windows heroku toolbelt.

This is the error process.

```
C:\Users\mads\businesszone>heroku run pip install pyodbc
Running pip install pyodbc on businesszone... up, run.9537
Collecting pyodbc
  Downloading pyodbc-3.0.10.tar.gz (68kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 4.3MB/s
Installing collected packages: pyodbc
  Running setup.py install for pyodbc ... error
    Complete output from command /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import se
tuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-jJIUQ3/pyodbc/setup.py';exec(compile
(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file_
_, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-J0_eAS-record/install-record.txt --single
-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pyodbc' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip-build-jJIUQ3
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip-build-jJIUQ3/pyodbc
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip-build-jJIUQ3/pyodbc/src
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstr
ict-prototypes -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=3.0.10 -DPYODBC_UNICODE_WIDTH=2 -I/Applica
tions/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacO
SX10.8.sdk/usr/include -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -c /tmp/pip-build
-jJIUQ3/pyodbc/src/cnxninfo.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip-build-jJI
UQ3/pyodbc/src/cnxninfo.o -Wno-write-strings
    cc1plus: warning: command line option `-Wstrict-prototypes' is valid for C/O
bjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
    In file included from /tmp/pip-build-jJIUQ3/pyodbc/src/cnxninfo.cpp:8:0:
    /tmp/pip-build-jJIUQ3/pyodbc/src/pyodbc.h:52:17: fatal error: sql.h: No such
 file or directory
     #include <sql.h>
                     ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__fil
e__='/tmp/pip-build-jJIUQ3/pyodbc/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open
', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --r
ecord /tmp/pip-J0_eAS-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-mana
ged --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-jJIUQ3/pyodbc/
```

I have also tried to install some of the old pyodbc version through pip and thorugh the zip's from the old google code project:
https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/pyodbc/pyodbc-3.0.7.zip

UPDATE:: You need to make your own heroku buildpack. see pic.
[image]

[image: help output on heroku server]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @whieronymus see update

Comment: Thanks @MadsVJ did you get it up and running?

I ended up using an alternative Buildpack and driver that I found on the Heroku Buildpacks page. I didn't see one there that worked for unixodbc/pyodbc, but there was one for freeTDS/pymssql (https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/m1schka/heroku-buildpack-python). I tested the pymssql library and the api/functionality was (almost) identical to pyodbc. So I ported my existing code (just one small class really) from pyodbc to pymssql installed the buildpack and am now up and running.

Comment: The only caveat is that the github repository for the buildpack I'm using hasn't been updated in 3 years. I'm going to use it for now and when the time comes, I'll look into creating my own buildpack. Reading through the docs (for heroku buildpacks) some of it went over my head, so I'm going to stick to whats working for now and refactor later on if I need to.

Comment: I ended up using another database solution and just took dumps uploaded dumps from the company database weekly.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have the unixODBC dev package installed. I'm not exactly sure how to install on Heroku, but here are two examples:

Example for Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev
```

Example for CentOS:

```
sudo yum install unixODBC-devel
```

You'll probably also want to look into installing a virtualenv as well, rather than doing a system-wide install of `pyodbc`.

Comment: Thanks you for the reply, @flipperPA !
The Heroku server does not support sudo commands. I guess i need to look into how to install modules like unixodbc on Heroku servers.

I have a virtualenv, i just did the command to force the error - should probably have stated that.

Comment: @MadsVJ did you find out a way to do this?

Comment: I used pypyODBC instead.